# Ty and Relay application id's in free diameter source code

Tags: free-diameter

In packet capture we can see Ty and Relay application ids in CEA. These seem to be hardcoded in free diameter source code. What will be the impact if we remove these.

Comment: Hmmm... What happens if you try doing so?

Comment: In unit test I see no impact after removing Ty and Relay app IDs. Only difference is I saw spurious retransmissions in packet capture randomly. But that is not impacting functionality. Not performed stress test yet.